# Three.js - How can I calculate the distance between two 3D positions?

Tags: camera, three.js, distance, mesh, between

I've already tried searching several different things on Google. Doesn't seem like I'm able to find anything. Thought I might as well upload a question to Stack Overflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Where v1 and v2 are of type THREE.Vector3:

```
function distanceVector( v1, v2 )
{
    var dx = v1.x - v2.x;
    var dy = v1.y - v2.y;
    var dz = v1.z - v2.z;

    return Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz );
}
```

**Update:**
In the r74 release of three.js the method `.distanceTo( v )` can be used.

Comment: Can't see the reason why there was a down vote on this. Fixed it

Comment: I'm guessing it was downvoted because it wasn't in Javascript, which is what Three.js is written in, definitely not a reason to downvote imo. I just added an edit, thanks for the answer @gaitat

Comment: Downvoting as there's an existing function in Three.js. Could you update your answer to reflect that? Thanks!

Comment: @EugeneKulabuhov is this suitable?

Comment: @gaitat Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 31):

In three.js, to calculate the distance between two 3D positions, use the `Vector3.distanceTo()` method:

```
var distance = vec1.distanceTo( vec2 );
```

three.js r.74

Comment: does this return distance in meters?

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript:

```
function dist(x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1){

deltaX = x1 - x0;
deltaY = y1 - y0;
deltaZ = z1 - z0;

distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY + deltaZ * deltaZ);

return distance;
}
```

Comment: In three.js, use the `Vector3.distanceTo()` method: `distance = vec1.distanceTo( vec2 );`

Comment: @WestLangley, could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: @EugeneKulabuhov Done.